# Wikidata/SPARQL, get distinct items (object id) in result

Tags: sparql, wikidata

When I run the following query I get multiple rows of "Paul Gauguin" since there are multiple informations about his place/time of death, the same could of course happen on all other parameters as well.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birthplaceLabel ?birthdate ?deathplaceLabel ?deathdate ?imageLabel ?article ?articleEn
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P119 wd:Q5024152.
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P18 ?image.       
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P19 ?birthplace.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P569 ?birthdate.    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P20 ?deathplace.    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P570 ?deathdate.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
     ?article schema:about ?item.
     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://sv.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
   OPTIONAL {
     ?articleEn schema:about ?item.
     ?articleEn schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "sv,en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

Is there a way of only recive one of the same object id, and don't care about if there are other "versions" of the object.

I have tried a bit with nested queries but I can't get it to work. Are there som other ways?

Comment: this only works with the usage of aggregate functions. So you `group by` the `item` and then you have to do it for all the other values. The question here is, how do you handle multiple values of his place for example. This will result in which aggregate function you have to use

Answer (score 1):

This query will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription 
(SAMPLE(?birthplaceLabel) AS ?birthplaceLabel)
(SAMPLE(?birthdate) AS ?birthdate)
(SAMPLE(?deathplaceLabel) AS ?deathplaceLabel)
(SAMPLE(?deathdate) AS ?deathdate)
(SAMPLE(STR(?image)) AS ?image)
?article ?articleEn

WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P119 wd:Q5024152.
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P18 ?image.       
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P19 ?birthplace.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P569 ?birthdate.    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P20 ?deathplace .    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P570 ?deathdate.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
     ?article schema:about ?item.
     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://sv.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
   OPTIONAL {
     ?articleEn schema:about ?item.
     ?articleEn schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {  ?birthplace rdfs:label ?birthplaceLabel . 
                          ?deathplace rdfs:label ?deathplaceLabel .
                          ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel ;
                                schema:description ?itemDescription .
                          bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "sv,en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?article ?articleEn
```

As you can see, we use the `SAMPLE` function and group by all the variables that aren't sampled.
You could also replace `SAMPLE` with `GROUP_CONCAT` if you wish to see all the possible values taken by a property.
E.g. `... (GROUP_CONCAT(?deathdate; SEPARATOR="; ") AS ?deathdates) ...`

Note that `GROUP_CONCAT` takes strings as arguments.

Comment: Thanks! But then "birthplaceLabel", "deathhplaceLabel" and "imageLabel" is empty in the result, I guess since there is many "versions" of this. Would it be possible to get let say the "first" value of one of these in the result? Just so there is something to display on the site, the user would then go to Wikipedia and could read about all the other possible "birthdates" and/or see the rest of the images,

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I hadn't noticed this. I'll edit my answer shortly

Comment: I think the issue is with the way WikiData's label service works.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried around a bit with your code and found that if I add "?birthplace rdfs:label ?birthplaceLabel ." in the SERVICE section I almost get what I want.. The only thing that I cant get out with this is the itemDescription

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with a bit of modyfing of Valerio Cocchis answer.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription 
(SAMPLE(?birthplaceLabel) AS ?birthplaceLabel)
(SAMPLE(?birthdate) AS ?birthdate)
(SAMPLE(?deathplaceLabel) AS ?deathplaceLabel)
(SAMPLE(?deathdate) AS ?deathdate)
(SAMPLE(?imageLabel) AS ?imageLabel)
?article ?articleEn

WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P119 wd:Q5024152.
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P18 ?image.       
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P19 ?birthplace.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P569 ?birthdate.    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P20 ?deathplace.    
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P570 ?deathdate.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
     ?article schema:about ?item.
     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://sv.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
   OPTIONAL {
     ?articleEn schema:about ?item.
     ?articleEn schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "sv,en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". 
    ?birthplace rdfs:label ?birthplaceLabel . 
    ?deathplace rdfs:label ?deathplaceLabel .
    ?image rdfs:label ?imageLabel .
    ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel .
    ?item schema:description ?itemDescription .
  }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?article ?articleEn
```